# How to get the previous date from particular date in file reading using shell script

Tags: shell

```
previousDay=`date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "-1 day"`
finish_time1=$(grep -o -m1  "$previousDay [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]" sample.txt)
```

---

Here I am trying to find out the immediate previous date of giving a date.Here is sample.txt content

```
    2013-11-07 15:53:49 HB Thread alive (1)
    2013-11-07 15:53:49 heartBeatCallback starting fireHeartBeat
    2013-11-07 15:53:50 refreshPollingTime END
    2013-11-07 15:53:50 heartBeatCallback testing childpid
    2014-01-24 15:53:50 heartBeatCallback end
    2014-01-25 15:53:50 HB end callback call
    2014-01-25 15:53:50 uploadTSLog TS_LOG_FILE is /public/tmp/testomatic/ts_logs/2013-11-   07_08-21-19_ONEOS90-VOIP_SIP_11N_FT-V5.1R5E12_NB83163_FT4_T10_112741.log
    2014-01-27 15:53:50 uploadTSLog: no new logs to upload
    2014-01-27 15:54:50 HB going to sleep */
```

Comment: I want to get the immediate previous day of the given date.ex: given date is 2014-01-27 , I want next previous day as  2014-01-25

Comment: Not sure if I am getting the question right... if given date is `2014-01-27` and you want `2014-01-25`, why don't you change the `"-1 day"` part as `"-2 day"`?

Comment: No dynamically I have search  immediate previous day of date in file, In posted example I am taking yesterday day as given date and trying to find out previous date in the file

Comment: [10 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3165241/user3165241?tab=questions) and no accepted answer thus far.

Comment: Any one can tell me  how to find the previous date from file

Answer (score 1):

[edit 2 : trying to answer the REAL question : find, given a date, the last log-line just before that date...]

```
Date="2014-01-24"
awk -v d=$Date  '
   ($1 < d) { previous=$0 ; }
   ($1 >=d) { print previous ; exit ; }
     ' sample.txt
```

this outputs:

```
2013-11-07 15:53:50 heartBeatCallback testing childpid
```

==== below: for historical reason, my previous answer, thinking you wanted "previous day" of a given date... ====

[edit: it's for day-1, not day-2. Easily modified for day-2 by having another 60*60*24 seconds]

You need to find the "day -1" from a date.

I let you do some "man date", so I just give you the procedure, not the exact way to do it

Just

- convert the date to "seconds since Epoch",
- then take out 'more than a day, but less than 2' out of it (ie, retrieve 60*60*24 seconds +10000 seconds from it, for example),
- and it will give you a time (in seconds since Epoch) in the "day -1" range,
- and convert back that new amount of secondes since Epoch to the corresponding date

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Olivier Dulac, But dynamically I have search immediate previous day of any given date in file, In posted example I am taking yesterday day as given date and trying to find out previous date in the file

Comment: @user3165241: once you determine the "day-1", just use "date +..." to retrieve info on the day, month, and year that is, and use those infos to grep in the file.

Comment: File has to read in reverse order to find out the date which is less than given date

Comment: .. or read the file, keeping also the "previousline" in memory, and when you reach the current date, print "previousline".

Comment: .. I think you asked the wrong question. I just now understand what you really want to do : find, in a logfile, given a date, the last line "just before" that date. It could be day N-1, or N-10, whatever... I'll propose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
finish_time=0
previousDay=`date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "-1 day"`
if [ $finish_time -eq 0 ]; then
tac logfile.txt | 
(
while read line
do
finish_time=`echo $line | sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9] [0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'`
file_content_date=`date -d "$finish_time" +%Y%m%d`
comparison_prev_date=`date -d "$previousDay" +%Y%m%d`
if [ $comparison_prev_date -ge $file_content_date ]; then
comparison_end_date=$(date -d "$file_content_date" +%Y%m%d)
break
fi
```

done
)
fi